# @RequestBody always retuning empty JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I'm facing some trouble when making `POST` request in SpringBoot using JSONObject as `@RequestBody`. Always it returns an empty `JSON` object as follows:

```
@PostMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Travel> create(@RequestBody JSONObject travel) {
        
        try {
            
            System.out.println(travel.toString());
.
.
.
.
```

[image]

But I am requesting with all fields in postman:

[image]

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: Have you tried `@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`?

Comment: @Turing85 yeah, same thing happens.

Comment: Try using a dedicated POJO class or a `Map` instead of `JSONObject`.

Comment: Use `String` instead of JSONObject and then do `JSONObject travelObj = new JSONObject(travel);`. Looks like your JSONObject is not able to deserialize the incoming json string. Also check org.json JSONObject version with spring version compatibility and one more last option could be use JSONObject from Gson which I think has inbuilt deserialization capability.

Comment: @AlexShesterov thank you, I created a AddTravelDTO.java and used it in the RequestBody and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the @AlexShesterov comment. I changed the `JSONObject` at the `@RequestBody` to a `POJO` class as follows:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AddTravelDTO {
    
    private Long id;
    private String orderNumber;
    private String amount;
    private String type;
}

public ResponseEntity<Travel> create(@RequestBody AddTravelDTO travel) {
.
.
.
```